# dont want to overwrite my ini file

Tags: c#, user-interface, ini

I am using ini file to store my configuration in my c# gui.
but when i start my gui again , and save the configuration, the previous saved configuration gets overwritten.
IS there a way to keep on saving configurations ?

Comment: What do you mean - do you want to save lots of different configurations and choose between them? Which one should be loaded when you restart your GUI?

Comment: why are you using ini? this is like 10 years old. use XML and object serialization/deserialization. all your problems here will be solved.

Comment: Maybe check whether the ini already exists before saving?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Not really... the XML file will also be overwritten.

Comment: @Kabbalah - sure about that? if you deserialize your objects, then modify it... then you serialize it back to the XML file... even the objects you do not modify will be serialized back to disk as if they were not touched.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas bit of a bold statement, although I agree INI files are old but they can still do a job. In fact, I bet most people would find it easier to modify an INI file than they would an XML file.

Comment: when I press the save button ,the configuration saves into the ini file and my program runs. When i start the gui again, and select different configuration and press the save button, the previous configuration is overwritten.

Comment: @user2862843 - show code. James - yes but XML is pretty much bread and butter.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I was assuming that the OP doesn't want anything to be overwritten. Not even modified objects. His latest comment seems to confirm that.  
I agree with you that OP should show some code especially his save methods.

Comment: I want all the previous configurations saved not overwritten

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an `app.config` file instead of your .ini.  You access the settings in it using the `ConfigurationManager` from the `System.Configuration` namespace.  You can even create custom configuration sections by creating classes that inherit from `ConfigurationSection`.  That will give you intellisense support of your config file, as well.

One example of that (it's using asp.net, but it works for any .net code) is [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/11/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx).

**Edit**: Re-reading your question, I'm unclear on if you're trying to save application settings (`app.config`), or if you're trying to save session data to disk (saving records or serializing objects).  If the former, look at `app.config`.  You can even have multiple items that set the same "settings" but with different values (such as having multiple SQL Connection strings) and then call them by some parameter you obtain from a user.

If you're trying to save session data/state, then you want to serialize your objects- look into serialization/deserialization (many options available there) and the System.IO namespace for persisting to disk.

Comment: And what if the OP needs user-specific configuration?

Comment: @James That's where my suggestion if using XML and serialization comes in play

Comment: @Ahmedilyas you can use *any* sort of file for user-specific configuration, it's not the format of the file that matters it's the usage.

Comment: @James - agreed and I know :) XML is far more common and more cross compatible, if needs to be, with other areas and platforms. its more flexible.

Comment: With custom config sections, I *can* have user specific configuration.  And if I'm saving data (rather than "configuration") I've updated the answer to discus serialization/deserialization.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas "*more cross compatible*".."*more flexible*" - more flexible than a text file (which an INI file ultimately is)? Doubt it. It's more *modern* yes and it is becoming more the standard nowadays but I re-iterate that it's not the solution to everything.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas that's because you don't really have a point - you are suggesting that XML is better than an INI file but don't provide any *real*, *concrete* evidence to support it. This is a specific app built for a specific purpose - it's up to the user to decide what type of format is best for their application, saying "use XML it will solve all your problems" isn't really a solution is it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent overwriting the same file each time is to make the file name unique e.g.

```
FileName<TimeStamp>.ini
```

Or

```
FileName<Guid>.ini
```

Or you could even do what windows does with duplicate files and check how many already exist and append a new number onto the end e.g.

```
FileName.ini
FileName1.ini
FileName2.ini
```

Personally I would go with the timestamp/GUID approach. Here's some example code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            SaveConfiguration();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    private static void SaveConfiguration()
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"Config\File\Dir", String.Format("Config{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.ini", DateTime.UtcNow));
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, "File contents");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2862843 no other way to save the same file without overwriting an existing file? No, their isn't. Unless of course you simply append the new configuration to the same file.